# Contents of object exists when var_dump'd, but not when being directly accessed

Tags: php, laravel, orm

So, I have this code:

```
$pInfo = ProductVariants::has('Product')->where('id','=',$item['variant_id'])->first();
```

Which works as it should when I var_dump the contents:

```
var_dump($pInfo); die;
```

But when I try to access it directly

```
$image = $pInfo->image;
```

It throws 'Trying to get property of non-object.'

But the weirder thing is that if I do

```
$image = $pInfo->image;
die($image);
```

It works as it should!

What in the world is going on

Comment: show us the results of the dump

Comment: The problem is in somewhere else in your code, after `$image = $pInfo->image;` you have other statements.

Answer (score -1):

When you dump it, are you sure, that it dumps Object? Maybe it is an array. When you try to access array element as a property, then you get exactly the error you got.

Could you please show the results of var_dump and die()?

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: "Maybe it is an array. When you try to access array element as a property, then you get exactly the error you got. " >> That's actually the reason for the problem, i believe.